# How do I test run Memurai on Windows

Tags: java, windows, redis, jedis, memurai

I have installed [Memurai](https://www.memurai.com/) on my Windows 10 64-bit system. Memurai is a Redis-compatible in-memory cache and persistent datastore running on Windows. I followed the steps given in [Installation steps](https://docs.memurai.com/en/installation.html). Memurai can be installed as a Windows service during the initial setup, or later using the command line options.
How can I create some basic applications with Memurai on Windows to taste the water. May I write some simple Java applications to use Memurai as a set-get store and test other features as well?
Need some guidance and pointers.

Similar to Jedis that works for Redis as a client, is there any such client API available to test as standalone server as single instance, or through some connection pool or connection cluster, where each cluster may have one or more connection pools to do load balancing? Some sample code, tutorial would help using Java.

Answer (score 7):

Memurai is 100% compatible with the Redis protocol (version 5), so any client library that works with Redis 5 should also work with Memurai, including Jedis.

Your best resources to start would then be tutorials and documentation for the Jedis library. Here’s one that walks through initial setup and demonstrate usage of a few server features through the client library: https://www.baeldung.com/jedis-java-redis-client-library. You might also want to check out the Jedis GitHub repo: https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis#how-do-i-use-it.